# Is multi folder opening possible?

Tags: c#

Think you have an open window that target **C:\Musics**

There are some files here and we know files name is there to select some of them (not one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853 This is the link to the command line argments available.  /select works only with one file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but [`OpenFileDialog.Multiselect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect.aspx) *may* be what you're looking for.

Comment: how to select some files with C# in explorer window ?

Comment: @pedram: It's really not clear what you mean. Have you already opened up the application? Do you want a context menu? Please give more context in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select files direclty in an windows exlporer window. At least not easily. It would require heavily COM-interfacing and knowledge.

What you can do is to support drag and drop from the explorer folder into your application, or as jon meantioned, use and OpenFileDialog.